# Solving multiple partial differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve following PDE's for functions `Xt,Xx,Xy` using `DSolve` but to no avail-

```
killing={2*Derivative[1, 0, 0][Xt][t, x, y] == 0, 
Derivative[0, 1, 0][Xt][t, x, y] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][Xx][t, x, y] ==0, 
Derivative[0, 0, 1][Xt][t, x, y] + Derivative[1, 0, 0][Xy][t, x, y] == 0, 
2*Derivative[0, 1, 0][Xx][t, x, y] == 0, 
Derivative[0, 0, 1][Xx][t, x, y] + Derivative[0, 1, 0][Xy][t, x, y] == 0, 
2*Derivative[0, 0, 1][Xy][t, x, y] == 0};
```

I am trying to solve by-

```
DSolve[killing, {Xt[t, x, y], Xx[t, x, y], Xy[t, x, y]}, {t, x, y}];
```

Can anyone help me figure out the problem.

Comment: Are those supposed to be derivatives like (1,0,0) is D[Xt[t,x,y],t]?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Let me edit the question.

Comment: Your system is overdetermined, as the message `DSolve::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables than equations, so the system is overdetermined.` indicates: Six pde`s >< 3 functions!

Comment: All three components of `X` being constants certainly is a solution.  I doubt that there are other solutions.